# Apache 2.4 // FilesMatch

Tags: apache-httpd

I wonder why test.html is Forbidden (as expected) but wp-login.php is available. I tried both FilesMatch and Files. They have similar "chown" and "chmod". I've read official Apache 2.4 docs. I googled a lot. I can not understand what's wrong in this correct config, and why wp-login.php is always available. How could it be denied for access?!

```
<Directory /home/user/html>

Require all granted
Options -Indexes

   <FilesMatch "^wp(.*)$">
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all denied
        Require ip 10.145.13
    </IfModule>
  </FilesMatch>

  <FilesMatch "^test(.*)$">
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all denied
        Require ip 10.145.13
    </IfModule>
  </FilesMatch>

</Directory>
```

**EDIT**

Thank you Philip,
I also thought about something like this - includes and so on...

> When you browse to /wp-login Apache is not loading wplogin first.

Not sure, because there's no such a directory /wp-login , there's just a file wp-login.php and I open it directly - http://...my..blog/wp-login.php

By the way, I remembered just now - it worked like a charm when I used Apache 2.2. Now I have 2.4, but the Wordpress remains the same. As we know, 2.4 has different syntax. So, I adopted new config to serve in the same way as my old 2.2 config. But...

That's strange.

And I found an article https://www.saotn.org/wordpress-htaccess-security-best-practices-apache-24/
Though, I configured everything in the same way before. Just to confirm that my settings are correct.

So, I'm not sure what to do.

UPD: found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32487034/apache-2-4-restricting-access-to-wp-login-php-by-ip-not-working

Answer (score 0):

This will be to do with wordpress's architecture.   When you browse to `/wp-login` Apache is not loading wplogin first. Instead rewrite rules are used to rewrite the URL.

Off the top of my head I can't remember the entry point but a different PHP file is called from Apache with `wp-`login as an argument.

That other PHP file then includes wp-login.php. Apache cannot control this.

These rules are often stored in a .htaccess file.

To prove this you can temporarily disable Apache from using .htaccess files an disable all other rewrite rules.

For a permanent solution you could tweak the rewrite rules to reject or ignore wp-login.php with added conditions.